# World line and light cones in two dimensions

Tags: proof-explanation, general-relativity, special-relativity

The following is an example of hartle :

Consider the two dimensional metric
ds^2 = -X^2 dT^2 + dX^2
And the world line X(T)=A cosh(T)
where A is a constant with the dimensions of length. The light cones are the curves with ds^2=0 that have slopes dT/dX = +-1/X

A particle's world line is time like if the size of its slope |dT/dX| is bigger than 1/X

Can somebody explain how writer claims that

1. dT/dX should be +1/X and -1/X
2. world line is time like if the size of its slope is bigger than 1/X

Comment: Those are definitions. What's there to explain?

Comment: So we can just define anything as we want without any reasons?? 

Comment: The reason is that definition will be used afterwards.